# Find lines with common words in two files

Tags: perl, unix, sed

#### File 1

- apache2-devel-2.0.59-5.2
- apache2-doc-2.0.59-5.2
- apache2-example-pages-2.0.59-5.2
- apache2-mod_perl-2.0.3.99-1.1
- utempter-32bit-9-200407011229
- apache2-worker-2.0.59-5.2
- apache2-prefork-2.0.59-5.2

#### File 2

- apache2-devel-2.2.12-1.38.2
- apache2-doc-2.2.12-1.40.1
- apache2-example-pages-2.2.12-1.40.1
- apache2-mod_perl-2.0.4-40.19
- utempter-32bit-0.5.5-106.20.1
- apache2-worker-2.0.59-5.2
- apache2-prefork-2.0.59-5.2

I want list of software which has different versions. For instance all but the last two here have different versions. The order may be different.

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: do the files always have the same software on the exact same line, with just the version different?

Comment: No they can be in any order and software's list can also be different. I mean whats there in file 1 may or may not be in file 2. But i need only those which are in both files with different version.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Are the hyphens `-` in your post part of the files, or did you mean to create an unordered list? Please show the *real* contents of the files

Comment: @Borodin I _think_ it's just the output of `rpm -qa`. See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-list-installed-rpm-package/) for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Borodin has put me in the right direction with his comment on your Q: The files you show seem to be the output of `rpm -qa`.

Sample:

```
$ rpm -qa | head -5
aaa_skel-2006.5.19-0.3
glibc-i18ndata-2.4-31.30
release-notes-sles-10-43.51
sles-stor_evms_en-10.1-0.10
yast2-schema-2.13.5-0.13
```

There are some switches to `rpm` which affect that output, namely the `--queryformat` option. See here http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-query-parts.html for details (scroll down to the "Tags" section).

With that switch it's possible to define the output format and separate package name, version, and release number with custom strings:

```
$ rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}\t%{VERSION}\t%{RELEASE}\n' | head -5
aaa_skel    2006.5.19   0.3
glibc-i18ndata  2.4 31.30
release-notes-sles  10  43.51
sles-stor_evms_en   10.1    0.10
yast2-schema    2.13.5  0.13
```

I used a tab `\t` here but any other unique character/string works as well.

If it's possible for you to re-write your file lists that way it is *far* simpler to distinguish between names and numbers because a simple `split(/\t/)` will do.

I know this isn't the full answer to your question but I will amend it if you can tell whether `rpm -qa --queryformat` is an option for you.
If I'm totally wrong, please tell and I'll remove my post.

Comment: @quorious: Please take note of this post. Your question is already void of any evidence of effort on your part to solve this yourself. If your data does indeed come from `rpm` then you are also withholding useful information that could help us to solve your problem. People give their time for free to help people like you, and it seems only fair that you should try your best to help us to find you a solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I put together quickly that should at least give you a starting point. I cheat on entries like `utempter-32bit-9-200407011229` that are ambiguous to parse.

Note that if you have extremely large files, you may want to take a different approach, as the first file is slurped into memory in its entirety.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh1, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'f2.txt' or die $!;

my %f1; 

while (<$fh1>){
    chomp;
    next if ! check($_); 
    my ($app, $ver) = separate($_);
    next if ! $app;
    $f1{$app} = $ver;
}

while (<$fh2>){
    chomp;
    next if ! check($_); 
    my ($app, $ver) = separate($_);
    next if ! $app;

    if (exists $f1{$app}){
        if ($ver ne $f1{$app}){
            print "$app version differs\n";
        }
    } 
} 

sub separate { 
    my $line = shift; 
    if (my ($app, $ver) = $line =~ /(.*?)-(\d+\..*)/){
        return ($app, $ver);
    }
}
sub check {
    my $line = shift;
    if ($line !~ /\./){
        print "* can't parse $line, check manually\n";
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
* can't parse utempter-32bit-9-200407011229, check manually
apache2-devel version differs
apache2-doc version differs
apache2-example-pages version differs
apache2-mod_perl version differs
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are going to be other edge cases, but the sample input was pretty brief.

Comment: Thanks its lot of help. I'll try to tweak the logic a bit more in my way.

Answer (score 1):

This program seems to do what you need

Separating the software name from its version number is arbitrary, so as a best guess I've used all fields that contain only decimal digits and dots `.` as the version number, and everything preceding that as the name

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Sort::Naturally 'ncmp';

my @files = qw/ file1.txt file2.txt /;

my @info = map { read_file_info($_) } @files;

my @software = do {
    my %sw;
    ++$sw{$_} for map { keys %$_ } @info;
    sort keys %sw;
};

for my $sw ( @software ) {

    print "$sw:\n";

    my @versions = map { $_->{$sw} // '' } @info;

    if ( $versions[0] eq $versions[1] ) {
        printf "    Version %s in both files\n", $versions[0];
    }
    else {
        for my $i ( sort { ncmp($versions[$a], $versions[$b]) } 0 .. $#files ) {
            printf "    %s in %s\n",
                $versions[$i] ? "Version $versions[$i]" : "Doesn't appear",
                $files[$i];
        }
    }

    print "\n";
}


sub read_file_info {
    my ($file) = @_;

    use autodie;

    open my $fh, '<', $file;

    my %info;

    while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;

        my ( $software, $version ) = split_name_vn($line);
        $info{$software} = $version;
    }

    \%info;
}


sub split_name_vn {
    my ($s) = @_;
    return ( $1, $2 ) if $s =~ /^(.+?)-([\d.-]+)$/;
    return;
}
```

#### output

```
apache2-devel:
    Version 2.0.59-5.2 in file1.txt
    Version 2.2.12-1.38.2 in file2.txt

apache2-doc:
    Version 2.0.59-5.2 in file1.txt
    Version 2.2.12-1.40.1 in file2.txt

apache2-example-pages:
    Version 2.0.59-5.2 in file1.txt
    Version 2.2.12-1.40.1 in file2.txt

apache2-mod_perl:
    Version 2.0.3.99-1.1 in file1.txt
    Version 2.0.4-40.19 in file2.txt

apache2-prefork:
    Version 2.0.59-5.2 in both files

apache2-worker:
    Version 2.0.59-5.2 in both files

utempter-32bit:
    Version 0.5.5-106.20.1 in file2.txt
    Version 9-200407011229 in file1.txt
```

Comment: Great. The real issue here is _How to separate names from version numbers?_. You found a very reasonable way in your `split_name_vn` function.

Comment: @PerlDog: Indeed. However the "proper" way is to get the source of the data to separate them for us, as you described in your own answer. Maybe I'm feeling especially ratty tonight!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/[-0-9.]+$/) {
    pkg = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    ver = substr($0,RSTART+1)
}
NR==FNR { p2v[pkg]=ver; next }
ver != p2v[pkg]

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
apache2-devel-2.2.12-1.38.2
apache2-doc-2.2.12-1.40.1
apache2-example-pages-2.2.12-1.40.1
apache2-mod_perl-2.0.4-40.19
utempter-32bit-0.5.5-106.20.1
```